# How to enable SSL 3 in Java

Tags: java, ssl, poodle-attack

Since Java 8 Update 31 the SSL 3 protocol is disabled by default due to security flaws in the SSL Protocol (see [POODLE attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POODLE)).

Even if not recommended, how can it be enabled?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unless you have no choice other than using SSL 3, the link below explains the configuration.

The [release notes for the update 31](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u31-relnotes-2389094.html#newft) provide information for enabling the SSL 3 again in Java.

As stated:

> If SSLv3 is **absolutely required**, the protocol can be reactivated by
>   removing "SSLv3" from the jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms property in the
>   java.security file or by dynamically setting this Security property to
>   "true" before JSSE is initialized.

Keep in mind that even the TLS protocol can be exploited to allow an insecure access with SSL 3, thats also part of the POODLE flaw. Enabling this for Java or any other technology should be a last resort only for critical reasons.

Comment: which property need to be set to true.."by dynamically setting this Security property to "true" before JSSE is initialized."

Comment: Since it says "dynamic", I assume it means using code, programmaticaly.

Answer (score 10):

If you must re-enable SSLv3.0 on either 8u31, 7u75, 6u91 all you have to do is comment out the following line in **JRE_HOME/lib/security/java.security**:

```
 jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3
```

Code:

```
import javax.net.ssl.*;

public class SocketProtocols {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    SSLSocket soc = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket();

    // Returns the names of the protocol versions which are
    // currently enabled for use on this connection.
    String[] protocols = soc.getEnabledProtocols();

    System.out.println("Enabled protocols:");
    for (String s : protocols) {
      System.out.println(s);
    }

  }
}
```

Output:

**Before enabling SSL 3.0**

```
$ /jdk1.8.0_31/bin/java SocketProtocols
Enabled protocols:
TLSv1
TLSv1.1
TLSv1.2
```

**After enabling SSL 3.0**

```
$ /jdk1.8.0_31/bin/java SocketProtocols
Enabled protocols:
SSLv3
TLSv1
TLSv1.1
TLSv1.2
```

credits/source: http://javablogx.blogspot.de/2015/02/enabling-ssl-v30-in-java-8.html

Answer (score 9):

You can set the `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` security property at runtime like so.

```
static {
    Security.setProperty("jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms", "");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found both of these edits were required in order to connect to a DRAC 5 card:

Remove MD5:

```
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, RSA keySize < 1024
```

Remove SSLv3, RC4, and MD5withRSA:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=DH keySize < 768
```