# How to enable SSLv3 in Java 8 without modifying java.security file?

Tags: java, ssl, java-8

In JDK 8 SSLv3 is disabled and TLSv1.2 is enabled by default.

When i google i found lot of posts where SSLv3 is enabled by commenting out the line in `java.security` file in the lib folder.

I want to enable SSLv3 by setting a system property with out modifying the java installation.

Comment: Bad luck, you can't.

Comment: @EJP And really shouldn't...

Answer (score 2):

You *might* be able to do this.  First, you need to check if your `java.security` file has the following line in it:

```
security.overridePropertiesFile=true
```

If so, then the following tricks might work.  Otherwise, if overriding the properties file is **not** allowed, then modifying that `java.security` file is your only recourse.

Assuming overriding the properties file is allowed, then you could try making a copy of `java.security` somewhere else, *e.g.* `sslv3-allowed.java.security`, with the `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` property value modified to have "SSLv3" removed from it.  Then, when you start the JVM, you'd use something like:

```
$ java -Djava.security.properties==/path/to/sslv3-allowed.java.security ...
```

Notice the "=="; this tells the JVM to *completely ignore* `java.security`, and use **only** your file.  With a single equals sign, your file can append to (or override) portions of the default `java.security` file.

The above come from reading this post: https://dzone.com/articles/how-override-java-security; a related SO post can be found here: [How to enable SSL 3 in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28236091/how-to-enable-ssl-3-in-java).

Hope this helps!