# SSLV3 not working even after disabling tls

Tags: tomcat, sslv3, sslv2

I have configured ssl on tomcat, and dislabled tls support on IE, and enabled ssl support, but still i get erro message saying

```
Turn on TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, and TLS 1.2 in Advanced settings
```

Tomcat setting

```
 <Connector
       protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
       port="8443" maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       keystoreFile="C:\OpenSSL\bin\PAS\keystore.jks"   keystorePass="******"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="SSLV3"/>
```

Comment: What java version are you using? From java8 update 31 and up SSLv3 is disabled by default for security reasons, so you [need to manually enable it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28236091/how-to-enable-ssl-3-in-java), but you really shouldn't. These old SSL versions need to die.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but:  SSLv3 is deprecated for a reason. You should not use it.  Browsers are *removing support* for SSL so that in the future, you won't even have the *option* to use it.  Do you have an exceptionally good reason for knowingly using a deprecated, insecure protocol when better alternatives are available?

Comment: Hello Wyzard, I want to use SSLv3 support fo r testing, i need to make sure that and capture sslv3 support before and after screenshots, I am using java 8, SO how do i enable SSLV3 for java 8?

Comment: Don't waste your time and use at least TLS 1.0. There is nothing to test with SSL 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the `sslProtocol` configuration directive with `sslEnabledProtocols`. Please have a look at the [Tomcat Configuration Guide](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html) for the difference between these two attributes.

In short:

- `sslProtocol` is used to choose the engine to be used. Choosing SSL or TLS will essentially give you the same behavior
- `sslEnableProtocols` chooses which exact protocols will be used for handshahkes (e.g. `SSLv3`, `TLSv1.2`, etc.)