# How to bring send.mail from mailR to work on Mac Mini?

Tags: java, r, email

I'm using `mailR` for sending emails from within `R`. This used to work just fine on other machines. That was before my Mac Mini. I can run `install.packages(c("rJava", "mailR"))` without any problems. However when sending, I run into errors that (based on what has been asked before) seem to be related to Java.

Here is my code:

```
library(rJava)
library(mailR)

smtp_list = list(host.name = "smtp.sendgrid.net",
                port = 587,
                user.name = "XXX",
                passwd = "XXX",
                ssl = T)

body_html_test <- "<html><meta charset='UTF-8'><p>Hello<p></html>"

send.mail(from = "some@adress.com",
                 to = "my@adress.com",
                 subject = "This is a test",
                 body = body_html_test,
                 encoding="utf-8",
                 html = TRUE,
                 smtp = smtp_list,
                 authenticate = TRUE,
                 send = TRUE)

NULL
org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.sendgrid.net:465
at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1410)
at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1437)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at RJavaTools.invokeMethod(RJavaTools.java:386)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.sendgrid.net, port: 465;
nested exception is:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2055)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:697)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:386)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:194)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1400)
... 6 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.<init>(HandshakeContext.java:171)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshakeContext.<init>(ClientHandshakeContext.java:101)
at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.kickstart(TransportContext.java:238)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:394)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:373)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:543)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:348)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:215)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2019)
... 13 more
Error: EmailException (Java): Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.sendgrid.net:465
```

At first I was inclined to believe that this has to do with my mailclient but based on what others have asked, this seems to be related to `java`. The fact that this script runs smoothly on other machines points into that direction as well.

OS version:

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 11.2
BuildVersion:   20D64
```

Java version:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_291"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_291-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.291-b10, mixed mode)
```

R version:

```
$ R
R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31) -- "Shake and Throw"
Copyright (C) 2021 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
```

R Java configuration:

```
$ R CMD javareconf
Java interpreter : /usr/bin/java
Java version     : 1.8.0_291
Java home path   : /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
Java compiler    : /usr/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/bin/jar

trying to compile and link a JNI program 
detected JNI cpp flags    : 
detected JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server -ljvm
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -    DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
conftest.c:1:10: fatal error: 'jni.h' file not found
#include <jni.h>
         ^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [conftest.o] Error 1
Unable to compile a JNI program


JAVA_HOME        : /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
Java library path: 
JNI cpp flags    : 
JNI linker flags : 
Updating Java configuration in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
Done.
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: You seem to be connecting to port 465 which [uses SSL](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/getting-started-smtp/#send-an-smtp-email-using-telnet). Support for SSL 3.0 [was dropped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28236091/how-to-enable-ssl-3-in-java), so I'd recommend connecting to one of the ports that supports TLS instead (rather than enabling the insecure cipher suite).

Comment: Yes but the same code runs perfectly on another machine...? Additionally, the port is specified above to be ```port = 587```...

Comment: Code that runs on one machine can fail on another, or even fail on the same machine on a different run. The stacktrace indicates it's connecting to port `465` in any case, which is why I assumed it's failing because it's trying to negotiate an unsupported cipher suite. Try using `tls = T` instead of `ssl = T` as seen [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mailR/versions/0.4.1) (under the MS Exchange server).

Comment: Switching from ```ssl=TRUE``` to ```tls=TRUE``` results in the same error message but instead of failing to connect to port ```465``` (as in the original question) it now fails to connect to ```587```...

Comment: Well, at least now you see that you weren't connecting to the port you thought you were. That's why reading error messages is worth a lot more than reading configuration values. Why don't you run the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36981532/2541560) to see which cipher suites are enabled.

Comment: Finally, @Kayaman Thank you for pointing me into the right direction. Enabling SSL 3.0 did work out for me.

Comment: I'm more surprised about the TLS not working. SSL 3.0 being disabled is normal, but why didn't you have a suitable TLS cipher suite? There should be v1.2 available. Enabling an insecure cipher suite might not be the best course of action.